# How to create a function to change the visibility of any given object with the visibility property in C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there any way to create a function in C# that can change the visibility of an given object that has the visibility property?

```
public void changeVisibilityState(Button test)
{
    if (test.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        test.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        test.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Like this but for any object with the visibility property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use more common object that implements `Visibility` property. For example `UIElement`. 
From msdn:

> UIElement is a base class for most of the Windows Runtime UI objects
>   that have visual appearance and can process basic input as part of
>   your app's user interface

So use something like this:

```
 public void ChangeVisibilityState(UIElement test)
    {
        if (test.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            test.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            test.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

This way you can pass to this function anything that inherits `UIElement`

Comment: Thanks, This was exactly what i needed!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, be sure to accept it :)

Comment: Have to wait 3 more minutes;)

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted. **Every object with "visibility" property** :

```
public static void changeVisibility(this object obj, Visibility vis) {
    var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("visibility", BindingFlags.Instance);
    if ( property != null ) {
        property.SetValue(obj, vis);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This wasn't what i meant though, so i changed the question a little bit.